# Wie sagt man "I have a sinking feeling" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar

> Sein Vater hat ihm bestimmte Anweisungen gegeben, dass er nicht mit
>   einem Unbekannten sprechen darf, außer wenn der Polizist ist.

`His father gave him specific instructions that he must not talk to a stranger unless it's a policeman. Because he has a sinking feeling that something is going to happen.`
`

Wie sagt man "I have a sinking feeling that something is going to happen" auf Deutsch?

Comment: What research have you done or attempts have you made?

Comment: Sagen die Wörterbücher nichts?

Comment: Nein. Meine Wörterbücher sind altmodisch.:)

Comment: "... hat ihm bestimmte Anweisungen gegeben ..." klingt doch sehr verkopft. "... hat ihn instruiert ...", "... hat ihm befohlen ...", "... hat ihn davor gewarnt ..." oder einfach "... hat ihm gesagt ..."

Comment: Kann man in diesem Zusammenhang "mir wird bange ums Herz" sagen?

Comment: Oder auch "... hat ihm (ausdrücklich) verboten, mit Unbekannten zu sprechen, außer wenn es Polizisten sind." - Seltsamerweise ist es nämlich so, daß der Ausdruck "bestimmte Anweisungen" gerade Unbestimmtheit in einen Satz bringt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Er hat ein mulmiges Gefühl, dass etwas passieren wird", would be the closest answer here.

Comment: or *beunruhiges Gefühl*